# Get message from Log groups connected on Cloudwatch Alarm with metric filtrer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a log group associated with a lambda.

I create metric filter for this log groups, like this:

[image]

I create one alarm for this metric filter:

[image]

The alarm is activated when I receive in my log group a message containing "technical.ERROR"

Then i'm notified by email because i set up my alarm to publish in a sns topic, i'm subscriber for this topic.

When I receive the email, **I would like to have the complete message of the log for which my alarm was activated**.

Currently I only have one json that tells me only that an alarm has activated for the metrics filter I specified before.

The only solution it is to create a **subscription filter** (and not a **metric filter**) that triggers a lambda that publishes on an SNS topic?

Thank's for you'r help.